# How can I stop the points on a path extending past the path

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs5

The path seems to extend past the point.  I have two paths and ideally I would like them to touch as in the end I would like them to be one single shape that I could fill in.  But my paths clearly extend beyond the point in the image.  How can I avoid this situation?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

I found that if you use the lasso to select your anchor points.  Then you can use the button in the following picture (looks like scissors on a path).  That button will keep all of the lines within the range of the original path.

Answer (score 4):

In the **contour panel** you can set the corner style to rounded; that should hopefully be enough to make the path stay inside the shape. (Sorry, my Illustrator is in German)
[image: defining corner styles]

Alternatives:

1) if you are sure your artwork is finished, go to Object > Path > Contour Line (outlines your paths) and then cut off the excess via pathfinder or manual editing. This makes it much harder to edit the path's shape in the future.

2) Instead of drawing one continuous path with 5 segments, draw 5 line segments. Then you avoid the spiking corners. Also makes it harder to edit the path in the future.

Comment: I did try the rounded corners but it wasn't what I wanted.  i did want straight corners, but just to stop at the point.  The way below worked best for me.  Although I'm sure someone else will definitely want the rounded corners.