# How to add handles for a bezier curve to a point on a path in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs5

Sometimes  to make life easier I <kbd>ctrl</kbd> & click on a point to remove the handles.

Sometimes I delete a point and it makes a straight line.  In that case I need my handles back again.

Sometimes I have only one handle.

How can I add the bezier curve handles back again?

*I'm using Adobe Illustrator CS5.*

[image: Only one handle]

Comment: Under the Bezier tool there is list of  a subtools if you hold the button down on top of the icon. The tool called convert anchor point can do this for you.

Comment: Hi Eoin, is your answer a comment? If yes, use the comment field to make comments of your question. Is your answer an addition to the question? If yes, edit the question and insert it there. Have you accepted any answer to all the questions you have asked? So far it seems that you are not satisfied with any of the answers to all the questions you asked. If you do not accept them, the questions are still open, and I see that in several cases you have already obtained the correct answer.

Comment: @Danielillo he has self answer timer on. So maybe he wants to accept his own answer. In either case its a valid answer and was done while i was typing my comment.

Comment: Honestly, I just feel guilty about giving myself the right answer when others also provided good answers.  But even so I cannot accept my own answer.

Comment: @Danielillo I have updated all the answers I consider correct.  Thanks for pointing that out.  Feel free to update your answer and I'll mark you as the correct answer.

Comment: If anyone can help me to understand how to reduce my minus points by explaining what I did wrong with my question that would also help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **Pen Tool** + <kbd>Alt</kbd> > Click the point and drag

or

- **Direct Selection Tool** > select the point or points and click **Convert Selected Anchor Points to Smooth**  [image: icon]  at the **Top Menu Options**

[image: Convert Selected Anchor Points to Smooth]

Comment: The second option does not appear in CS5 for some reason.  The pen option works, which is useful thanks.

Comment: I just saw the **Convert Options** that I put in the answer at the top-left of [this capture](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/113812/120647) you insert in one of your questions

Answer (score 2):

This is for the latest Adobe Illustrator CC.

This method is especially useful if you also want to keep the corner anchor as a corner. Choose the Direct Selection Tool (A), and move it over the path near the corner anchor which has no handle.

The cursor will change into a little bend icon, and you can click and drag the path to extend another handle where one did not exist previously.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I worked this out, but also someone else commented with the answer. Click and hold on the pen tool and you will find the "convert anchor point tool".

Select it and find your point.  Now click and drag and you will see the handles come out at which point you can resume normal service.

[image: convert anchor point tool]